# Unexpected behaviour of async Fat Arrow inside of array

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

EDIT: Can't replicate that behavior anymore, but this was happening in node v14.7.0. Everything is back to normal, I can just pass a normal callback `() => <AsyncFunction>()` and it works ... Maybe something went wrong with the debugging environment that I am using and it didn't load the updated code, I don't know.

I thought that having the `async () => <function>()` Syntax would create a function that is then placed into the array of `interruptRunner`, instead it immediately executes and therefore puts a promise in the array.

I am confused to why that is, it shouldn't execute. Putting brackets `async () => (<function>())` around the return type resolves the issue but I am not sure to why it executed in the first place. I thought immediate execution is only possible with IFFE's.

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Twiggeh99/2duc8g1q/2/)

```js
const interruptRunner = async actions => {
  for (let action of actions) {
    await action();
  }
};

// Didn't work, is the solution though
await interruptRunner([
  () => sleep(2 * 1000),
  ...
]

// Didn't work, executed like IFFE
return await interruptRunner([
  async () => await ticket.origMsg.author.send(msg),
  async () => await sleep(60 * 1000),
  ...

// Worked, functions were received instead of pending promises
await interruptRunner([
  async () => {
    await ticket.origMsg.author.send(msg);
  },
  ...

//  Works, but with not needed asyncs 
await interruptRunner([
  async () => (await sleep(2 * 1000)),
  async () => (await sleep(2 * 1000)),
]);
```

Comment: What's `interruptRunner`? It's not defined for me in Node or my browser, and searching for it doesn't bring up anything obviously related.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Its in the JsFiddle, it's not relevant to the question though. The question is why the fat arrows execute and put promises into the array instead of themselves as funcions

Comment: your doesn t work is not in the fiddle, please add it, also you ve got unnecessary asyncs...

Comment: I don't think they *do*; I can run `[async () => await ticket.origMsg.author.send(msg), async () => await sleep(60 * 1000)]` despite `ticket` not being defined, as expected, hence I wonder what `interruptRunner` is doing that makes you think they're being executed before it's called. And @EugenSunic is correct - in fact the `await` is pointless too whether or not the arrow function is declared as `async`.